# Grunt. Compile all .jade files when child (_*.jade) included

Tags: javascript, html, gruntjs, pug

I have next structure:

```
jade
├── _skeleton.jade
├── _header.jade
├── _footer.jade
|
├── includes
│ └── _include-on-index.jade
│ └── _include-on-page-1.jade
│ └── _include-on-all-pages.jade
|
├── pages
│ └── index.jade
│ └── page-1.jade
│ └── page-2.jade
│ └── page-3.jade
```

And I need to setup jade compile, like some apps, (for example Prepros).

It means that if I edit page-3.jade I need compile only page-3.jade, if I edit file that start with _*.jade, I don`t need compile exectly this _*.jade file like html, but I need to compile all .jade files that included this _*.jade file

For example when I edit file _header.jade, I need compile all files that included _header.jade, if I edit _include-on-index.jade I need to compile file without _ that included _include-on-index.jade

Can I do this with Grunt?

Answer (score 1):

you can use **grunt-contrib-jade** and **grunt-contrib-watch** and insert a watch for this jade files.

so let's say everytime when you change a .jade file the watch will see this change and will compile your file.

assuming i have this tree:

**jade/templates**
with all my .jade files

**jade/compiled-templates**
with all my compiled jade templates for .html

config for jade:

```
//Jade ===============================
            config.jade = {
                    compile: {
                        options: {
                            client: false,
                            pretty: true
                        },
                        files: [ {
                          cwd: "jade/templates",
                          src: "**/*.jade",
                          dest: "jade/compiled-templates",
                          expand: true,
                          ext: ".html"
                        } ]
                    }
                }
```

config for watch:

```
    //Watch ===============================

    config.watch = {
         scripts: {
            files: ["jade/**/*.jade"]
            ,tasks: ["dev"]
         }
    }
```

I hope this answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for helping! 
I try this code, but, it compile all files, when I edit only one.
And another problem: it compile files, that starts with _.jade as single html.

Here is my code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqexjK?editors=0010

Comment: **Raduken**, can You help me please ?

Comment: I will do a test to see.

Comment: I did some tests but I could not solve your problem, looks like that task is deprecated i suggest to you try find another one, about the other problem i suggest you use jade includes for your _.jade  : http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/ , I hope that will help you.